# Marquee tag in html? how we can use this tag in different ways?

Tags: html, css

I want to use this tag on images.

I want that images should flow from left continously, but there is a delay after all the images have crossed the right margin of the tag and taking approx.5-6sec. to appear from left margin.

Comment: `marquee` has been deprecated, you can use javascript to achieve this target.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can probably do what you want without needing JavaScript, but we will struggle to help without seeing the basic HTML structure you have. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://codeconvey.com/css-animation-ticker-tape-of-images/